# Multidimensional vector bus error

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I have a `11663 Bus Error` when I attempt to do the following;

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > bullets;
std::vector<int> num;
num[0] = 7;
bullets.push_back(num);
```

I thought this would work as the vector `bullets`'s type is a vector. Why doesn't this work as expected? Also, the following works;

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > bullets;
std::vector<int> num (4, 100);
bullets.push_back(num);
```

And I don't know why this works, but not my other code.

Comment: I'm not positive, but i think people think your vector is empty...

Comment: @AK4749 be positive. you're exactly correct. =P

Comment: @WhozCraig haha I don't know, with all the strong emotions surrounding .push_back() here, I thought I'd temper the mood with some careful probing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> num;
num[0] = 7;
```

`num` has not yet allocated storage for anything.  Only use the indexing syntax `[]` if you know an element exists at that index.  Otherwise, use `push_back`, which grows the `vector`s storage capacity if needed.  The second example works because you used the constructor which reserves a certain amount of space for elements (4 in this case, all with the value 100).

```
std::vector<int> num;
num.push_back(7);
bullets.push_back(num);
```

---

On a side note, "this doesn't work" is not a very helpful problem description.  Also, note that a vector of vectors used as a matrix is not a good idea in performance critical code should you need to iterate over each element.

Don't scrap it just yet and don't worry abut it unless you *know* for a fact that it will be a problem, but realize that you lose locality of data with this approach because each vector will allocate its storage separately.  If this data is being iterated over in a tight loop you are better off allocating one big vector and calculating the offset to each individual position manually.

Comment: +1: Unless the OP has some strange matrix ideal where row-size can vary inter-matrix, Ed is entirely correct on the assessment of allocating an N*M matrix a a single N*M element vector<>.

Comment: I'm still messing around with how many elements need to be in my vector, but I will attempt to use offsets :) thanks!

Comment: @jackwilsdon: I wouldn't worry about it at this point, but it is something you need to understand down the road.

Answer (score 0):

```
num[0] = 7;
```

should be

```
num.push_back(7);
```